# Why when I write noexcept before const i get an error

Tags: c++, c++17

Why when I write definition of a class member function such as

```cpp
int returnSize() const noexcept
```

the code compiles, but when I write

```cpp
int returnSize() noexcept const
```

it doesn't compile

Comment: Exception specifiers have to be inserted after function reference and const/volatile qualifiers or, in the case of lambdas, before the mutable qualifier, if present, and before the optional attributes.

Comment: `const` is applied to whatever is to the left of it (if there is nothing to the left, then it applies to whatever is to the right.) `noexcept` is not something that can be `const`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's just the way the language is defined.

Exception specifiers need to come after const/volatile qualification:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

[image: function]